# Loading Office UI Fabric fonts and icons with Content Security Policy

Tags: office-ui-fabric

As part of the `font-src` [policy directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), fonts can only be loaded from whitelisted domains. When I enable a default CSP using Office UI Fabric, all fonts and icons are blocked from these locations:

`https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/assets/fonts/*`and `https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/assets/icons/*`

Is there documentation on the CDN locations used for fonts & icons? What domains do I need to whitelist to enable CSP for office ui fabric?

There is some discussion of CSP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599944/content-security-policy-and-office-ui-fabric) but it specifically handles the `style-src` directive, not the `font-src` one.

Thanks

Niko

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Using-icons#alternative-cdn-options
Maybe download from the source repo and host it locally and refer to that hosted location during runtime via the `initializeIcons()`?
Note: I haven't actually tried this so I can't confirm or deny, just posting doc link in case you missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer here! The domains you listed are correct, and as far as I'm aware (I work on Fabric) they should stay the same at least while Fabric 7 is the current release.

Info about the CDN domains (and how to change them if you want to do that) is documented [here for icons](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Using-icons#alternative-cdn-options) and [here for general fonts](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Customizing-fonts#changing-the-cdn).